Eclipse Scout Property Change Event from Javascript to Java
I wanted to ask how a JavaScript execute a PropertyChangeEvent for Java.
I am trying to fill a StringField in Javascript. However, since it is readonly by the property (enabled = false), set in Java-Client, the value is set in the field, but neither the value nor a change are triggered in the Java area of my Eclipse Scout project. If it is not readonly, I can use it without any problems and carry out further steps in the Java area, or even react to it at all.
So I thought I could use a change event to trigger it manually. But that doesn't seem to work either. Neither trigger(), onchange, addEventListener(), on(), nor change() seem to work.
I load the input field for the StringField like this:
let myValue = "MyContent";
/* get inputfield */
let myField= $(`div[data-modelclass~="my.project.path.MyForm$MyRootGroupBox$MyStringField"] input`);
/* set value */
myField.focus().val(myValue).blur().click();

I have to admit that I don't have a lot of experience in events, but if I use different examples from the internet, one of them should actually work. Does anyone have any idea how to do this, or at least know that it really can't work?

I only half understand what you're trying to do here, and honestly, it makes very little sense to me. What exactly type of UI are you using and how is it in contact with the javascript?

I am using the Framework Eclipse Scout, the most Packages (Maven) are using Java for Example Server, Client, Shared. And one Package use web languages (NPM, PNPM, HTML, LESS, JS/TS, node_modules). the java Classes are conneted to js/ts-classes. the Framework is mostly used for web apps. Eclipse Scout Version 24.1.3

That's not a bug, it's a feature! Only model code on the UI server is allowed to alter the model state. Value change events from the browser are simply ignored. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

I wanted to fill the StringField in a JavaScript as I wrote it (code) because I'm using an external device that works with JavaScripts. But for the user, the StringField should be read-only.
I've already solved the problem, but thanks for the answer. I created a CustomStringField where I set the “readonly” attribute instead of “disable” to continue using the events.
